# WP - Auto empty cart on homepage not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I'm building a site with a checkout, the site has 2 products, that need to be sold individually. So to prevent people from adding the first item, leaving the cart, then adding the second item, I wanted to set up the cart to auto-empty. So I decided to test it for the homepage. The initial function I had was this:

```
function my_empty_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
add_action('init', 'my_empty_cart');
```

That works perfectly. But the cart is always empty because of this. So I decided to add in an "if" statement:

```
function my_empty_cart() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_front_page() && isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_empty_cart' );
```

And that doesn't work...at all. I've tried it with "is_home" and "is_page" (with various page titles and ids). I even tried removing the "&& isset" part, just to test. At this point i'm lost, I've never had this much difficulty with a simple php code and i'm pulling out my hair at this point. Is there something simple i'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional tags (is_home(), is_front_page(), etc) don't work at the time the 'init' hook fires. You can use 'wp' hook instead. It runs immediately after wp class object is set up (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp).

```
function my_empty_cart() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_front_page() && isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
     $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_empty_cart' );
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me (dont relies on WordPress conditional):

```
/*empty cart if user come to homepage*/
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') { 
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
```

}

Comment: Im trying to get this to work with an javascript or ajax who triggers it before the user leaves the page. My first approach is with javascript with beforeunload, but it generates a unecessary dialog box.